# MVC6 - Handle unhandled exceptions and still have error page redirection

Tags: asp.net, exception, owin, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware

In my MVC6 application, I have created a middleware to handle global unhandled exceptions with Invoke task as below:

```
try
{
    await _next.Invoke(context);
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    ... Log the exception here...
}
```

The issue i am facing is, if i add this in the configure section before adding UseDeveloperExceptionPage/UseExceptionHandle, then catch block in middleware is not being hit.
When i add this after UseDeveloperExceptionPage/UseExceptionHandle, the error page or module are not getting processed.

How can i not disturb the error page/module but still catch the error in the pipeline and log it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Exception page needs to have an `Exception` object to work with. Your code catches the exception which is then suppressed. Try rethrowing the exception like so:

```
try
{
    await _next.Invoke(context);
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    //Log the exception here...
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Thanks elolos. I removed throw for some reason and didn't observe it was not there. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just re-throwing the error will cause the stack trace to show the error originated in your middleware. You will need to throw the error like this: `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e).Throw();`

Comment: `throw e;` will cause the stack trace to be lost, but doesn't `throw;` on its own do the same thing as `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e).Throw();`?

Comment: Yes you should only write throw; in c#. Doing throw ex; is a common java programmer mistake when writing c#.  So do something like catch (exception ex) {logger.log(ex); throw; }